# Etherscan claimed MANA, DEXE & REQ tokens creation tx's return different contractAddresses, they got an issue or I miss something?

Tags: contract-development, etherscan, erigon

For example, Mana token page at Etherscan is https://etherscan.io/token/0x0f5d2fb29fb7d3cfee444a200298f468908cc942

Mana contract page at Etherscan is https://etherscan.io/address/0x0f5d2fb29fb7d3cfee444a200298f468908cc942 (same hash as above)

At the contract page the following page is claimed to be the token creation tx page https://etherscan.io/tx/0xc276acd60857b70bc986f6ccf0d2b968411b4194f02c34050f708e536d9369e9

When I query my local Erigon node using eth_getTransactionReceipt and the above creation tx hash, I see that the contractAddress field actually got a different value than the stated token hash - 0xa66d83716c7cfe425b44d0f7ef92de263468fb3d (instead of 0x0f5d2...)

Most of the tokens I checked do return the expected contractAddress.

Am I wrong to expect the contractAddress to be equal to the token address which is claimed? if not, does that mean that Etherscan is displaying wrong information?

Thanks!

Comment: Noticed the same @ https://eth.blockscout.com/token/0x0F5D2fB29fb7d3CFeE444a200298f468908cC942 and other explorers as well, somehow they all know that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it's also possible to create contracts using an internal tx with a type of CREATE or CREATE2 and that's the case for the above tokens

Comment: For readers to understand it better, add an explanation on how internal transactions using CREATE or CREATE2 can output different contract addresses.